# Phrase for "whatever comes to mind" or "whatever I feel like"

Tags: phrase-requests

I had a friend, also learning Japanese, presenting "words of the day" (日の言葉). I asked him (and you are free to tear this sentence apart):

> どこから日の言葉出るの？
>
> "Where do the words of the day come from?"

He replied with:

> やりたいのはやる
>
> "I do the ones I want to do"

Which is understandable, but it just seems... unnatural to me. Maybe I'm completely off the mark.

Thinking about how to say it, I considered the English things I might say, like "whatever I feel like" or "whatever comes to mind", but neither seemed right when I tried to translate it.

What are some good ways to express the idea of "doing whatever comes to mind" (maybe related to whimsy?).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Words of the day" could be [今日]{きょう}の言葉, 今日の[一言]{ひとこと}, or maybe [一日]{いちにち}一言 (*lit.* a phrase a day).

> "Where do the words of the day come from?"

I would probably say it as 「今日の言葉は、どうやって考えるの？」-- literally: "How do you think of the words of the day?"

> "whatever I feel like" or "whatever comes to mind"
> "doing whatever comes to mind" (maybe related to whimsy?)

How about using phrases like...

> 「思いつくままに」
> 「思いついたことを何でも」
> 「何となく」/「何となく思いついたことを」
> 「気分で」/「その日の気分で」